# Stripe Connect API (Ruby) with a "Managed Account": delete bank account, add multiple bank accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm implementing the Stripe Connect API using the [Stripe API Reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#update_account) when necessary. There are two problems I haven't been able to solve using that reference:

1) Is it possible to delete a bank account? If so, how? I've tried calling standard `delete` and `destroy` methods on the bank account object, as well as `.destroy_all` on `account.bank_accounts`. `account.bank_accounts.first = nil` also doesn't seem to work.

2) Is it possible to add more than one bank account? The fact that the parent `Account` object has a `.bank_accounts` makes it seem like this should be possible, but the only way I can find to add a bank account is with `account.bank_account=` which allows you to create or update a single account.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a NodeJS application using Stripe and I had these exact same questions. After talking to Stripe Support:

1. As far as I've gathered, there's no way to remove a bank account. I'm waiting on confirmation from Stripe Support, and I'll update here as soon as I get a response.
2. A single account (A managed account in my case), can have one bank account linked to it *for each currency*. So one, and only one, bank account which accepts USD. But it's possible to add another bank account accepting GBP. It seems like this is why the `bank_accounts` method is named so. Using their Node library, calling the `update` method with a `bank_account` property populated replaces an existing bank account if one of the same currency already exists.

I was hoping someone from Stripe would respond here (and still am), but until then, I hope this is helpful.